# Pages stack can be managed by either the Widget (AutoRouter.declarative) or the (StackRouter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am using Declarative Routing from AutoRoute flutter package.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
final _appRouter = AppRouter();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
        routerDelegate: AutoRouterDelegate.declarative(   
            _appRouter,
            routes: (_) => [
              // if the user is logged in, they may proceed to the main App
              if (authService().isLoggedIn)
                HomeRoute()
              // if they are not logged in, bring them to the Login page 
              else
                LoginWrapperRoute(onLogin: () => authService().logIn),
            ],
        ),
        routeInformationParser:
            _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(includePrefixMatches: true));
}
```

}

```
IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          context.pushRoute(const AlarmRoute());
        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications_active),
        color: const Color(0xFF666666),
      )
```

when I try to push or navigate to a page it gives me this error:
Widget': Pages stack can be managed by either the Widget (AutoRouter.declarative) or the (StackRouter)

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

As per the author of `auto_route` on [their comment](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/496#issuecomment-907175724):

> You can't use `context.pushRoute` (imperative) if you use the
> declarative navigation, `AutoRouterDelegate.declarative`. . You have
> to pick one.

There are many issues open so it would be great if `auto_route` can implement an improvement.

### My solution:

I avoid using the "declarative" approach by `auto_route`, but I still have similar code. Near the root of my app, I had:

```dart
          return AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: settingsController,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
              return MaterialApp.router(
                restorationScopeId: 'app',
                routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(
                    initialRoutes: (settingsController.settings.showOnboarding)
                        ? [const OnboardingRoute()]
                        : [CurrentPoseRoute()]),
                routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
                theme: ThemeData(),
                darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
                themeMode: settingsService.settings.themeMode.toMaterial(),
              );
            },
          );
```

My `settingsController` uses the mixin `ChangeNotifier`, so I could use `notifyListeners();`.

This does build a big piece of widget tree though. For me, it doesn't matter because I use this when switching from onboarding to normal user flow.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I switched to `go_router` since I need declarative routing.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know you switched, interesting to know. 

Answer (score 1):

I think, you only need initial route. from author [on his comment](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/433#issuecomment-808872868)

> i'd await for the auth service so the moment I run the App I know
> whether my User is authenticated or not and from there I can either
> use an AutoRouteGuard to guard the home page (to do the redirecting)
> or simply pass either HomeRoute or LoginRoute as initialRoutes to the
> router delegate.

```
void main() async {
  var isAuthenticated = await authService.state;
  // native splash screen is showing until runApp is called
  runApp(MyApp(authenticated: isAuthenticated));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _appRouter = AppRouter();

  final bool authenticated;

  MyApp({Key? key, required this.authenticated}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(
        initialRoutes: [if (authenticated) HomeRoute() else LoginRoute()],
      ),
}
```

Then put your auth listener (i use Firebase auth) in home/ dashboard to listen your auth state. in the state, its free to redirect user wherever.